# can't scp a named pipe

Tags: linux, scp, fifo

I am trying to encrypt a file on-the-fly, redirecting the output to a named pipe [fifo].  I SSH into my server and run the command:

```
           $ mcrypt -k key < file > named_pipe
```

then from my laptop I try to scp it:

```
           $ scp me@server:~/dir/named_pipe
```

and it says

```
           scp: /users/home/me/dir/named_pipe: not a regular file
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: I would assume that `scp` copies file content. A named pipe is not a physical file, hence `scp` won't try to copy it (try copying `/dev/random`, for example). Just redirect to a file, or find a way to tunnel the data to your laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stream from it instead.

```
ssh me@server cat ~/dir/named_pipe > file.out
```

Comment: So I finally got around to trying it out:  this is what I get:  Bus error: 10 (core dumped).. from mcrypt, and the "> file" file is emtpy.

Comment: Try streaming from the named pipe locally to see if `mcrypt` invokes a bus error even then.

Comment: Good call.   I try it on a big file [900MB] and it seems to just sit there doing nothing [output being blank] So created a 5MB file from /dev/urandom, and tried encrypting to a regular file [no fifo].  And it invokes the bus error. :\  I try it on my local Ubuntu machine and it works fine.  Maybe it's this server or freebsd? :\  Do you of any encryption program to output to stdout?

Comment: Unfortunately command-line encryption is not my forte; I usually leave that to GnuPG or OpenSSL.

Comment: Turns out, I don't need this anymore.  However, your answer would have worked if mcrypt would work. :)

Comment: I am currently using a server that limits me to scp. Being able to trick scp into transferring the contents of a named pipe, so that I can transfer huge files without buffering them, would be a huge win for me.

Comment: ~ is resolving to my local home directory instead of the remote one.